# How to automatically add localhost DNS server (dnsmasq) to resolv.conf

Tags: domain-name-system, openvpn, dnsmasq, arch-linux, resolv.conf

I did the steps at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenVPN#DNS to set up DNS with OpenVPN so that anytime the OpenVPN connects or disconnects, it automatically updates /etc/resolv.conf.

The problem is that I've also got a DNS server (dnsmasq) running on localhost to resolve certain custom domains, and I'd like to add these entries to the generated /etc/resolv.conf. How can I do that?

I tried uncommenting the line `name_servers=127.0.0.1` in `/etc/resolvconf.conf`, but then the generated /etc/resolv.conf contains **only** that single line, rather than appending it to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something I ran into also.

Resolvconf can [generate configuration](http://roy.marples.name/projects/openresolv/wiki?name=config_dnsmasq) which [dnsmasq can read](http://roy.marples.name/projects/openresolv/wiki?name=config_dnsmasq).

Add to your resolvconv.conf

```
dnsmasq_resolv=/etc/dnsmasq-resolv.conf
```

And then to your dnsmasq.conf

```
resolv-file=/etc/dnsmasq-resolv.conf
```

This way, resolvconf will write the dns servers for dnsmasq in a special configuration file, instead of dnsmasq reading it from `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: This isn't working for me, have I done it correctly? Added the first line to `/etc/resolvconf.conf` and the second to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, then did a `sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq.service`. But `/etc/dnsmasq-resolv.conf` still doesn't exist. Do I need to run some `resolvconf` command?

Comment: The page you linked to also had some additional lines, which ones do I need to add to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`?

Comment: @user779159 You need to run resolvconv -u, which generates the necessary config for dnsmasq

Comment: That command does generate `/etc/dnsmasq-resolv.conf`, but now when I bring up or down the openvpn service, both dnsmasq-resolv.conf and resolv.conf get updated and look the same as each other. But I need a `127.0.0.1` to appear in /etc/resolv.conf (which is my local dnsmasq). If I add it manually everything works great but then as soon as I bring up or down openvpn the file gets overwritten and doesn't contain 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Did you remove the nameserver=127.0.0.1 part? This is still required.

Comment: Does this still work for you after the latest update to dnsmasq? It's no longer working for me.